# adding Apache Commons Lang3 to my Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, apache-commons-lang3

I am doing a Spring Boot exercise from Baeldung.com. The project has a test class that uses the method randomAlphabetic, which I have traced back to RandomStringUtils, which in turn belongs to Lang3 from Apache Commons. I can't seem to add the import of RandomStringUtils or even Lang3 itself to my project.

I have looked at the import on the GitHub [repository](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-bootstrap/src/test/java/com/baeldung/SpringBootBootstrapLiveTest.java) for the project. The project is done as a Maven project, but I have done mine as a Gradle project, because Gradle is what I use at work (I don't know Maven). I have added the following to my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.apache.commons'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
}
```

I have attempted the following import statements:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;
```

When I am writing my import statement and I put the period after commons, the autocomplete only comes up with two choices: logging and logging.impl . I do not even have an option to add lang3. I have also checked in the Spring Initializer to see if I could add lang3 there, but I cannot.

I have downloaded lang3 onto my computer. It contains 5 JAR files plus a lot of other material that I don't know how to use. I thought I could move those JAR files into my Project and External Dependencies 'folder,' but I can't find any way to do so. I'm using Spring Tools 4 Suite for Eclipse, btw.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Apologies if this is a dumb question, but did you build the project after adding the dependency?

Comment: Did you get any errors when you ran 'gradle build'?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to manually download the jar, if that's what you're describing. Gradle does that for you.

Comment: I tried a ./gradlew build but the build failed.

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.apache.commons'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

Comment: Is that the error you got?

Comment: In general, I believe you first have to do 'gradle init'. Did you do that? I believe that generates a settings.gradle file. Do you have that file in the project?